# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null (Leaflet Control Layer)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to make a control layer for my piechart. There is an console error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null. This is the picture of my error

[image]

I have to call the function again, but I don't know how to do that. I have searched for any other similar problem but not find the best answer for me yet.

```
var pieChartGroup = L.featureGroup();

vals.forEach((val) => {
  var pictures = L.marker(val.location, {
    icon: L.divIcon({
      className: "leaflet-echart-icon",
      iconSize: [160, 160],
      html:
        '<div id="marker' +
        val.id +
        '" style="width: 160px; height: 160px; position: relative; background-color: transparent;"></div>',
    }),
  }).addTo(pieChartGroup);
  //  Based on the prepared dom, initialize the echarts instance
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("marker" + val.id));
  //  Specify chart configuration items and datas
  option = {
    tooltip: {
      trigger: "item",
      formatter: "{a} <br/>{b}: {c} ({d}%)",
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: val.nama,
        type: "pie",
        radius: ["10", "25"],
        avoidLabelOverlap: false,
        label: {
          normal: {
            show: false,
            position: "center",
          },
          emphasis: {
            show: true,
            textStyle: {
              fontSize: "18",
              fontWeight: "bold",
            },
          },
        },
        labelLine: {
          normal: {
            show: false,
          },
        },
        data: [
          {
            value: val.MB,
            name: "Masih Bersekolah",
          },
          {
            value: val.TBL,
            name: "Tidak Bersekolah Lagi",
          },
          {
            value: val.TBPS,
            name: "Tidak/Belum Pernah Bersekolah",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
  //  Use the configuration items and data you just specified to display the chart.
  myChart.setOption(option);
});

var baseLayers = {
  OpenStreetMap: LayerKita,
  OpenCycleMap: L.tileLayer(
    "http://{s}.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  ),
  Outdoors: L.tileLayer(
    "http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/outdoors/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  ),
};

var overlays = {
  Bersekolah: pieChartGroup,
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Check whether `document.getElementById("marker" + val.id)` is `undefined`; if so, then delay initialization of the chart via `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Sorry, can give me an example. I dont know how to use settimeout(). I follow tutorial in the internet but not susccess yet